# Karate BDD can't locate classpath

Tags: java, testing, karate, bdd

I have below changes in my code and I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` (stacktrace is at the end). Can someone please help me to find what I am missing here?

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
       <build>
       <TestSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</TestSourceDirectory>
       <testSourceDirectory>${TestSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${TestResourceDirectory}</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
       </build>
```

```
package examples.users;

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

class UsersRunner {
    
    @Karate.Test
    Karate testUsers() {
        return Karate.run("classpath:/examples/users").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}
```

```
package examples;

import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
class ExamplesTest {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:examples")
                //.outputCucumberJson(true)
                .parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<String>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "API Tests");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'

    at com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.<clinit>(ResourceUtils.java:100)
    at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.resolveAll(Runner.java:204)
    at com.intuit.karate.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:177)
    at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:483)
    at examples.ExamplesTest.testParallel(ExamplesTest.java:23)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
```

Comment: most certainly a lib conflict perhaps because your pom is too complicated. see if using the "fatjar" helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#karate-core-fat-jar - or try to resolve the classpath yourself, or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I added <classifier>all</classifier> into Fat JAR which was missing earlier and it started picking the classpath.